# How to add URL strings for a Django app to a database and randomly select?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I built a small survey application which randomly assigns participants to one of 9 paths by randomly selecting the last part of the URL and appending it onto a button link. I then use e.g. `{% if 'surveyone' in request.path %}` etc. in my template tags to display the right content to the user.

This works fine on my local machine but I have since discovered Multi-threaded processing and using constant lists such as the below `SURVEY_URLS` has caused issues when the project is uploaded to the server. I want to instead store this in my database.

**Question(s)**

- How do I add/store the below `SURVEY_URLS` list of strings in my MySQL database?
- How do I remove particular URL strings from the same database? (as below)

The below is my existing code which has all the functionality I need and works fine on my machine. I just need to make it work correctly when dealing with multiple concurrent users.

Thanks

**views.py**

```
SURVEY_URLS = ['/surveyone/', '/surveytwo/', '/surveythree/', '/surveyfour/', '/surveyfive/', '/surveysix/', '/surveyseven/', '/surveyeight/', '/surveynine/']

def begin(request):

    total_path_counter = TotalCounter.objects.get_or_create(total_max_counter__gte=0)[0]  
    if total_path_counter.total_max_counter < 100:

        survey_url = random.choice(SURVEY_URLS)

        if survey_url == '/surveyone/':    
            survey_path_counter = SurveyCounter.objects.get_or_create(survey_wizard_type = 'survey_wizard_one')[0]

            if survey_path_counter.survey_wizard_count > 9: 
                SURVEY_URLS.remove('/surveyone/')

        elif survey_url == '/surveytwo/':    
            survey_path_counter = SurveyCounter.objects.get_or_create(survey_wizard_type = 'survey_wizard_two')[0]

            if survey_path_counter.survey_wizard_count > 9: 
                SURVEY_URLS.remove('/surveytwo/')

        ....
        ....


        elif survey_url == '/surveynine/':
            survey_path_counter = SurveyCounter.objects.get_or_create(survey_wizard_type = 'survey_wizard_nine')[0]

            if survey_path_counter.survey_wizard_count > 9:
                SURVEY_URLS.remove('/surveynine/')

        return render(request, 'Begin.html', {'survey_url': survey_url})    
    else:
        return render(request, 'surveyfull.html')
```

**Begin.html**

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="/experiment{{survey_url}}">Begin Instruction Tasks</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I suppose you can make a new model something like this:

```
class Survey(model.Model):
  name = models.Charfield(max_length=50) # surveyone goes here
  ...
```

than in the view you can pull the random like this:

```
survey_count = Survey.objects.all().count()
random_survey_index = random.randint(0, survey_count - 1)
```

get the instance name by `random_survey_index` and append it to your url

Not sure how effective this approach is, but should work.

Comment: Just a note that you *can* get a random object using `order_by("?")`, for example: `Survey.objects.order_by("?")`. However, this query may be slow depending on which database you're using. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by